# What is this encoding error for hevc encoding yuv file?

Tags: hevc

I tried to encoding hevc test sequence fileㅡfour peopleㅡwith HM 15.0(Hevc test encoder) but this process suddenly stopped when those sequence appeared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xSAJ.jpg

I just thought problem of config.cfg but I don't know error of my config file.

I attached my config file, If you discovered some problem, I would thank you

```
#======== File I/O ===============
InputFile                     : FourPeople_1280x720_60.yuv
OutputFile            : FourPeople_1280x720_60_out.yuv
InputBitDepth                 : 8           # Input bitdepth
FrameRate                     : 60          # Frame Rate per second
FrameSkip                     : 0           # Number of frames to be skipped in input
SourceWidth                   : 1280        # Input  frame width
SourceHeight                  : 720         # Input  frame height
FramesToBeEncoded              : 600         # Number of frames to be coded

Level                         : 4

#======== Unit definition ================
MaxCUWidth                    : 64          # Maximum coding unit width in pixel
MaxCUHeight                   : 64          # Maximum coding unit height in pixel
MaxPartitionDepth             : 4           # Maximum coding unit depth
QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize         : 5           # Log2 of maximum transform size for
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...6)
QuadtreeTULog2MinSize         : 2           # Log2 of minimum transform size for
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...6)
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthInter       : 3
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthIntra       : 3

#======== Coding Structure =============
IntraPeriod                   : 1           # Period of I-Frame ( -1 = only first)
DecodingRefreshType           : 0           # Random Accesss 0:none, 1:CRA, 2:IDR, 3:Recovery Point SEI
GOPSize                       : 1           # GOP Size (number of B slice = GOPSize-1)
#        Type POC QPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2  temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures 

#=========== Motion Search =============
FastSearch                    : 1           # 0:Full search  1:TZ search
SearchRange                   : 64          # (0: Search range is a Full frame)
HadamardME                    : 1           # Use of hadamard measure for fractional ME
FEN                           : 1           # Fast encoder decision
FDM                           : 1           # Fast Decision for Merge RD cost

#======== Quantization =============
QP                            : 32          # Quantization parameter(0-51)
MaxDeltaQP                    : 0           # CU-based multi-QP optimization
MaxCuDQPDepth                 : 0           # Max depth of a minimum CuDQP for sub-LCU-level delta QP
DeltaQpRD                     : 0           # Slice-based multi-QP optimization
RDOQ                          : 1           # RDOQ
RDOQTS                        : 1           # RDOQ for transform skip

#=========== Deblock Filter ============
DeblockingFilterControlPresent: 0           # Dbl control params present (0=not present, 1=present)
LoopFilterOffsetInPPS         : 0           # Dbl params: 0=varying params in SliceHeader, param = base_param + GOP_offset_param; 1=constant params in PPS, param = base_param)
LoopFilterDisable             : 0           # Disable deblocking filter (0=Filter, 1=No Filter)
LoopFilterBetaOffset_div2     : 0           # base_param: -6 ~ 6
LoopFilterTcOffset_div2       : 0           # base_param: -6 ~ 6
DeblockingFilterMetric        : 0           # blockiness metric (automatically configures deblocking parameters in bitstream)

#=========== Misc. ============
InternalBitDepth              : 8           # codec operating bit-depth

#=========== Coding Tools =================
SAO                           : 1           # Sample adaptive offset  (0: OFF, 1: ON)
AMP                           : 1           # Asymmetric motion partitions (0: OFF, 1: ON)
TransformSkip                 : 1           # Transform skipping (0: OFF, 1: ON)
TransformSkipFast             : 1           # Fast Transform skipping (0: OFF, 1: ON)
SAOLcuBoundary                : 0           # SAOLcuBoundary using non-deblocked pixels (0: OFF, 1: ON)

#============ Slices ================
SliceMode                : 0                # 0: Disable all slice options.
                                            # 1: Enforce maximum number of LCU in an slice,
                                            # 2: Enforce maximum number of bytes in an 'slice'
                                            # 3: Enforce maximum number of tiles in a slice
SliceArgument            : 1500             # Argument for 'SliceMode'.
                                            # If SliceMode==1 it represents max. SliceGranularity-sized blocks per slice.
                                            # If SliceMode==2 it represents max. bytes per slice.
                                            # If SliceMode==3 it represents max. tiles per slice.

LFCrossSliceBoundaryFlag : 1                # In-loop filtering, including ALF and DB, is across or not across slice boundary.
                                            # 0:not across, 1: across

#============ PCM ================
PCMEnabledFlag                      : 0                # 0: No PCM mode
PCMLog2MaxSize                      : 5                # Log2 of maximum PCM block size.
PCMLog2MinSize                      : 3                # Log2 of minimum PCM block size.
PCMInputBitDepthFlag                : 1                # 0: PCM bit-depth is internal bit-depth. 1: PCM bit-depth is input bit-depth.
PCMFilterDisableFlag                : 0                # 0: Enable loop filtering on I_PCM samples. 1: Disable loop filtering on I_PCM samples.

#============ Tiles ================
TileUniformSpacing                  : 0                # 0: the column boundaries are indicated by TileColumnWidth array, the row boundaries are indicated by TileRowHeight array
                                                       # 1: the column and row boundaries are distributed uniformly
NumTileColumnsMinus1                : 0                # Number of tile columns in a picture minus 1
TileColumnWidthArray                : 2 3              # Array containing tile column width values in units of CTU (from left to right in picture)   
NumTileRowsMinus1                   : 0                # Number of tile rows in a picture minus 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this answer. It help you encode test sequence.

You have to delete Level option of FILE I/O.